# How to Export latest Offer Start Date in TCC

Tags: taleo

I am trying above query but dosent work, can someone help.I am looking to export only the latest start date from Offers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best out of this site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any query present in your question, but I would suggest before writing any queries like max offer sequence etc , you try with "**CurrentOffer,ActualStartDate**" for exporting "**ActualStartDate**" or any other field path you require from your latest offer